# Css transitions not working: fade problems

Tags: html, css, web

Hi im using Microsoft Expression Web 4 to make a website and I want to make a link fade into another image when I hover over it
the code is:

```
.about { background: url('../images/aboutbutton1.png') no-repeat;
min-height: 50px;
max-width: 150px;
-moz-transition: background .45s linear;
-webkit-transition: background .45s linear;
transition: background .45s linear;
}

.about:hover {
background: url('../images/aboutbutton2.png') no-repeat;
min-height: 50px;
max-width: 150px;
-moz-transition: background .45s linear;
-webkit-transition: background .45s linear;
transition: background .45s linear;
}
```

But everytime I do it it doesnt fade it just switches! please help!

Comment: What browser are you testing with? It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5eVaB/

Comment: Note that fading is not yet as a standard and there for may not work in all browsers